# How to optimize a sequence of jQuery appends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

I have a series of jQuery appends that look like this:

```
moveControls.append("<span>").find("span").last().addClass("absLeft").text("«");
moveControls.append("<span>").find("span").last().addClass("left").text(" ‹ ");
moveControls.append("<span>").find("span").last().addClass("right").text(" › ");
moveControls.append("<span>").find("span").last().addClass("absRight").text("»");
```

And, writing it out, it seems... Messy, or convoluted. It works perfectly, but I was wondering if there was anything I should be doing instead. Maybe an 'append to' but I still would need to construct the s.

My biggest problem goes with the Append -> Finding the element I just added -> Getting the last element -> Adding classes + text.

I've repeated it several times through out my code, but as a novice, I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way to doing this.

If this is too broad of a question, I apologize. New to Stackoverflow, and this has been a concern for me.

Comment: Suggestion: Use pure js call to do this..

Comment: @Pilot My thoughts exactly. Just make your own function. *Real* programmers use the DOM directly.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm already using jQuery and not really interested in learning pure JS (at least, not yet.) But @rvighe, the idea of using my own function is one I should've thought of, before. And probably would've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is

```
$('<span />', {'class': 'absLeft',text: '«'}).appendTo(moveControls);
$('<span />', {'class': 'left',text: ' ‹ '}).appendTo(moveControls);
$('<span />', {'class': 'right',text: ' › '}).appendTo(moveControls);
$('<span />', {'class': 'absRight',text: '»'}).appendTo(moveControls);
```

But creating a string and appending it at the end will be more efficient

```
var arrays = [];
arrays.push('<span class="absLeft">«</span>');
arrays.push('<span class="left"> ‹ </span>');
arrays.push('<span class="right"> › </span>');
arrays.push('<span class="absRight">»</span>');
moveControls.append(arrays.join(''))
```

Comment: This is what I went with, a lot more concise, a lot more clear. The first example, that is, but nto with the arrays. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can place all your class and text in 2d array and loop it:

```
var arrList = [ ["absLeft","left","right","absRight"], ["«","‹","›","»"] ];

for(var i=0;i<arrList.length;i++)
      $('<span />', {'class': arrList[i][0],text: arrList[i][1]}).appendTo(moveControls);
```

By this your code will also be flexible to add more types in future.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to setup all your HTML that you're appending, then call jQuery's append() just once.

```
var arrows = '<span class="absLeft">«</span><span class="left"> ‹ </span><span  class="right"> › </span><span class="absRight">»</span>';

moveControls.append(arrows);
```

This cuts down on some of the repetitive jQuery code (optimizing readability), but may not optimize for efficiency as much as some alternatives others are suggesting.